# A continuous group action is an action by homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

In *An Introduction to Topological Manifolds*, Lee states that, given a topological group $G$ and a topological space $X$, an action is continuous if $f: G\times X\to X$ is continuous, and the action is an action by homeomorphisms if $x\mapsto g\cdot x$ is a homeomorphism.

He also states that the former implies the latter, and his reasoning makes sense if $f$ restricted to $\{g\}\times X$ is bijective for each $g$, but I don't understand why this must necessarily be the case.

Let $X$ be a copy of $G$. Let $f: G\times X\to X$ satisfy
$$
f(g, x) = 
\begin{cases}
x & g = e\\
0 & g \neq e
\end{cases}
$$

Let $U\subset X$ be open. If $0\notin U$, then $f^{-1}(U) = \{e\}\times U$. If $\{e\}$ is open, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.

Now, if $0\in U$, then $f^{-1}(U) = (G\times X) - (\{e\}\times U^c)$. If $G$ is $T_1$, then $\{e\}\times U^c$ is the product of two closed sets, and an open set minus a closed set is open; thus, $(G\times X) - (\{e\}\times U^c)$ is open.

So, if the topology on $G$ satisfies that the singleton of the identity element is both open and closed--say the discrete topology--then $f$ is a continuous function, but it's only a homeomorphism when $g = e$, so it wouldn't be an action by homeomorphisms.

What am I getting wrong here? Since Lee states that a continuous action is necessarily an action by homeomorphisms.

Comment: How is $0\in X?$

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with spaces - it's entirely a consequence of the definition of a group action on a set.

An action of $G$ on $X$ has to play well with the structure of $G$: writing "$g\cdot x$" for the action of the group element $g\in G$ on the set element $x\in X$, we have to have $$(gh)\cdot x=g\cdot (h\cdot x)$$ for all $g,h\in G$ and all $x\in X$, and moreover $e\cdot x=x$ for all $x\in X$ when $e$ is the identity of $X$. This automatically means that each map $x\mapsto g\cdot x$ must be a bijection, since **groups have inverses**.

A *monoid* action need not "consist of bijections," but a group action must.

Answer (score 1):

When a group, any group, **acts** on a set, any set, the action of any group element is a **bijection** of the set. This is so because the composition of the action of two elements is the action of their product, and every group element is invertible. Therefore, you should always be able to undo the action and return to the state where nothing moves (which is the action of the identity element).